# Alternative to lock for async operations

Tags: c#, async-await, synchronization

Hello i have the following problem:

I have a class `Pool` that contains a list of `Connection`-s.The `Connection` is a wrapper over a `socket`.I somehow need to create the `socket` ,`ConnectAsync`-it ,wrap it into a `Connection` and return it to the caller.The problem is that i need this this collection to be thread-safe.
Specifically i need the collection to be thread safe when i create a new `Connection` or when a `Connection` calls `Pool`-s `Free` method.

What alternative to the `lock` do i have? I have seen so far `SemaphoreSlim` but i do not understand it.

**Pool**

```
   internal partial class Pool    {
            public static Pool MakePool(UserSettings settings)
            {
                return new Pool(settings);
            }

            private List<Connection> liveConnections;

            private readonly object @lock = new object();

            public readonly UserSettings settings;

            public async  Task<Connection> ConnectAsync()
            {
                Connection readyConnection;
                lock(@lock)
                {
                    if (this.liveConnections == null)
                    {
                        this.liveConnections = new List<Connection>(this.settings.MIN);
                    }
                    readyConnection = this.liveConnections.FirstOrDefault(x => !x.IsUsed);
                    if (readyConnection == null)
                    {

                        readyConnection = await CreateConnectionAsync(settings);
                        this.liveConnections.Add(readyConnection);

                    }

                    return readyConnection;

                }
            }
            private async Task<Connection> CreateConnectionAsync(UserSettings settings)
            {
                //Socket initialization
                Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                IPAddress address=IPAddress.Parse(settings.HOST_NAME);
                int port = settings.PORT;
                IPEndPoint point = new IPEndPoint(address, port);
                await socket.ConnectAsync(point);


                ConnectionSettings conSettings = new ConnectionSettings
                {
                    pool = this,
                    ConnectionID = GenerateID(),
                    socket = socket,
                };
                Connection con= Connection.CreateConnection(conSettings);
                return con;

            }
            //this gets called by the connection !!
            internal void Free(string ID)
            {
                lock (@lock)
                {
                    Connection con=this.liveConnections.Find(x => x.ID == ID);
                    con.IsUsed = false;
                }
            }
            private static string GenerateID()=>Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            private Pool(UserSettings settings)
            {
                this.settings = settings;
            }

        }
```

**Connection**

```
public class Connection :IDisposable
    {
        private PhysicalConnection rawConnection;

        internal  static Connection CreateConnection(ConnectionSettings settings)
        {
            Connection con = new Connection(settings);

            return new Connection(settings);
        }

        public readonly string ID;
        private readonly Pool parentPool;
        public bool IsUsed { get; internal set; }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.parentPool.Free(this.ID);
        }



        private Connection(ConnectionSettings settings)
        {
            this.ID = settings.ConnectionID;
            this.parentPool = settings.pool;
            this.rawConnection = new PhysicalConnection(settings.socket);

        }
    }
```

**ConnectionSettings**

```
class ConnectionSettings
    {
        public Pool pool;
        public string ConnectionID;
        public Socket socket;
    }
```

As you can see the `Pool` is sent in the `Connection` constructor so that the `Connection` can notify the `Pool` when it is disposed !

Comment: Why do you need an alternative to lock?

Comment: Because i can not `await` in a lock.

Comment: If you want a thread-safe collection, why don't you use one that the framework provides like `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<T>`?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian Then what should happen to your collection while you're awaiting? Should it stay locked? Or you can unlock it at while awaiting?

Comment: @rs232 Yes it should stay locked.I want the operation of `opening a socket`,`wrapping it in a Connection` and `add Connection to collection` to be atomical.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian then it seems that you overcomplicate the task by using await. You want to lock the collection, then start an asyncronous operation (probably on another thread) which might take indefinite time and invoke indefinite number of other operations, and to unlock your collection only after that operation completes. This is a very dangerous behaviour as it is so easy to introduce nearly-impossible-to-identify race conditions. The code should be synchronous IMO: lock the collection, push in an item, unlock the collection, enjoy a working code.

Comment: I think you are right.I wanted to do  first `ConnectAsync` the `Socket` before wrapping it and adding it to the collection...but i suppose the `Connect` will do just fine.

Comment: Anyway if i use `await ConnectAsync` or `Connect` it is the same thing.The code will behave synchronously nonetheless.The only thing that differs is that in the latter case i get a state machine .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't even need to keep your call to CreateConnectionAsync inside the lock:

```
public async  Task<Connection> ConnectAsync()
{
   Connection readyConnection;
   lock(@lock)
   {
       if (this.liveConnections == null)
       {
           this.liveConnections = new List<Connection>(this.settings.MIN);
       }
       readyConnection = this.liveConnections.FirstOrDefault(x => !x.IsUsed);
   }
   if (readyConnection == null)
   {
       readyConnection = await CreateConnectionAsync(settings);
       lock(@lock)
       {
            this.liveConnections.Add(readyConnection);
       }
   }
   return readyConnection;
}
```

Your CreateConnectionAsync does not use liveConnections collection at all. At the point you've done with searching through the collection, so it can be unlocked while your new connection asyncronously tries to connect to its endpoint.

Comment: When i create a new `Connection` i must add it to the `liveConnections` list or else what would be the point of `this.liveConnections.FirstOrDefault(x=>!x.IsUsed)`.I must store it in the list to be able to check it at a later time.I updated my code so that you add the new `Connection` to the collection.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that part from the answer! Now updated.

Comment: So you must call `lock` twice to be able to do it.I supposed it is way too costly.

Comment: What function does your first lock actually do?

Comment: Your locks get very short and distributed in time. This is good. Then, lock is effectively a critical section, which is not that heavy comparing to kernel sync objects.

Comment: @Andrey it effectively prevents: a) creating two different collections, b) modifying the collection while iterating over it inside FirstOrDefault.

Comment: 1) It is better to create the list in the constructor then do it lazily or use `System.Lazy`  2) FirstOrDefault does not modify the collection 3) Instead of thread-safing the List better use ConcurrentList instead of locks

Comment: 1. That's a matter of preference. 2. It does not, but without lock the collection might be modified from outside WHILE executing FirstOrDefault. 3. What is ConcurrentList?

Comment: 1. No, it is not matter of preference. Fewer locks is better. Lazy initialisation should be used only if there are reasons to do it, eager is the default. 2, 3: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.getconsumingenumerable?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: 1. Your suggestion does not reduce the amount of locks since we still need to iterate over the collection. Again, while I agree that we totally CAN move the collection initialization to the class constructor or anywhere else, in reality it is NOT IMPORTANT. 2,3. This seems to be a pretty random link to msdn, it does not contribute to the answer at all.

Comment: @rs232 there is class BlockingCollection that basically does blocking for you and FirstOrDefault gonna be thread safe in combination with Add. I am pointing to the fact that there is number of ways to avoid locking entirely. You can use classical indexed `for` with List, because the only modification is appending.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pair of [ConcurrentBags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx), one for used and one for unused connections. Initialise them in the constructor and I think you won't need any locks at all.

Comment: But using 2 datastructures i still have to keep them synchronized.Whenever i push inside one i have to pop from the other.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian that push+pop shouldn't be an atomic operation as long as you pop before pushing.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian not really. it gonna be like this `x = c1.pop(); c2.push(x);` both pop and push individually are atomic and since only 1 thread is in the possession of x then it is safe. You usually should care only about thread safety of shared resources.